# Can't change window manager for lxsession

Tags: lubuntu, window-manager, lxde, lxsession

I am running Lubuntu 16.04.
This ships with openbox but I want to use ratposion.

The config file in `~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/desktop.conf` specifies the window manager like so:

```
[Session]
windows_manager/command=openbox
```

This works perfectly. However, I wanted to replace `openbox` with `x-window-manager` so that I could use `update-alternatives`. When I do this, the window manager fails to start with the following error message: `x-window-manager exit with this type of exit: 256`. The same thing happens if I use the command `ratpoison` instead.

Why does only openbox work?

How can I get lxsession to start ratpoison? (preferably without adding it to the `autostart` file as that feels like a nasty [hack/workaround])

Comment: Just to clarify, the error message I mentioned appears in the lxsession log file.

Comment: @DKBose good question, I tried it and got the same error. I also tried specifying an absolute path, that doesn't work either.

Comment: @DKBose I think that loads from the config file I was editing anyway. When I opened it the window manager was already set to x-window-manager. Changing the value just changes that config file. It still produces the error.

Comment: @DKBose I tried that, same error